# Change the Labels of Users to Customers in Admin

Tags: customization, users, admin, labels

Ok, I've been searching for over an hour for something I thought (and still think) is pretty simple.  I need to change the title Users to Customers in the admin for a client.  I can and have easily hooked into the menus and changed it there. But it still shows up as Users on the main users page or when you add a new user (Add new User should be Add New Customer).

I tried something like this in an init action but no dice ...

```
$labels = &$wp_post_types['users']->labels;
$labels->name = 'Customer';
```

I've got to be missing some very simple filter.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you mean `users.php` and `user-new.php`, then 'users' are not post type; 'users' have its own table. And you can use the [`gettext`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/) filter to modify the text 'User'/'Users'/etc. Just search for `__()` and `_e()` calls in the relevant PHP file.

Comment: Simple. I've had my head in custom post types so much for this project I wasn't thinking. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Sally CJ in the comments. gettext was the easiest and fastest way to make this possible.